# Filter data.table if and only if condition is verified despite NA

Tags: r, filter, data.table, na

I want to filter my data using conditions, but the presence of NA affects the results.

For example:

```
dt <- data.table(a=c(1:4,NA), b=c(NA,2,1,4,5), d=c(1,2,NA,4,NA))
dt

    a  b  d
1:  1 NA  1
2:  2  2  2
3:  3  1 NA
4:  4  4  4
5: NA  5 NA
```

when I do

```
subset(dt, !(b < a))
   a b d
1: 2 2 2
2: 4 4 4
```

i.e., if either a or b is NA, that row is excluded:

but the result I want is

```
    a  b  d
1:  1 NA  1
2:  2  2  2
3:  4  4  4
4: NA  5 NA
```

that is, I just want one row to be excluded if and only if the condition verifies.

If I add more conditions, like `subset(dt, is.na(a) | is.na(b) | !(b < a))` it works as expected but I was looking for a way to express 'if and only if' through operators like `&` and `|`

Is this possible?

Thank you!

Comment: I think the problem is that an expression like `NA < 4` will *never* verify (or falsify) in R, because *any* comparison with NA will not return a boolean but NA... I can't finde an alternative to checking for NAs (as you suggested yourself). Maybe someone more clever than me has a better/more satisfying solution for you ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works:

```
dt[!which(dt$b < dt$a), ]

    a  b  d
1:  1 NA  1
2:  2  2  2
3:  4  4  4
4: NA  5 NA
```

In this workaround I am only selecting the rows which don't return `TRUE` for condition `df$b < df$a`. Meaning they can return `FALSE` or `NA` or whatever really.

Comment: Thank you @denisafonin! Do you know if it can be done using `subset` or  `filter`? I've tried but the result is `Empty data.table (0 rows and 3 cols): a,b,d`

Comment: Can't figure out why this happens with `subset` or `filter` at the moment..

Answer (score 0):

We may use `if_any`

```
library(dplyr)
dt %>%
    filter(if_any(c(b, a), is.na)|b >=a)
    a  b  d
1:  1 NA  1
2:  2  2  2
3:  4  4  4
4: NA  5 NA
```